# how to get nullpointer exception in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nullpointerexception, null

As known, in ObjectiveC ,we can sendmessage to a nil object and won't throw nullpointer exception. But it also makes some bug difficult to find out. So is there some way to make program throw nullpointer exception or crash, when executing code in our debuging like this .

```
NSString * s = nil;

int n = [s intValue];
```

I want this code can make program crash, so I can find out this bug easier.

Comment: You should read the Exceptions programming guide and consider NSAssert macros.

Comment: I recommend that if you write Objective-C code you go with the flow of the language. Very often being passed a nil pointer is no problem. If it is a problem, NSAssert is your friend.

Comment: @Tirth: Have you done any Objective-C programming at all? The code will run just fine and set n to 0.

Comment: You could use a breakpoint in objc_msgSend with a condition on the first parameter equal zero. The problem with this approach is that it would break all the time. All of the franeworks send messages to nil all of the time.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe  your approach is what I want, but how we can make a breakpoint to objc_msgsend? We only have header file for objc_msgSend (/user/include/objc/message.h), If we make a breakpoint  to this function in header file, this breakpoint isn't useful.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Can symbolic breakpoint take effect ? but what should we  write in condition input field. 'self == nil'?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a safe check method for every object you want to use.

I prefer category for NSObject class

```
@implementation NSObject (Utility)
    +(id)checkSafe:(id)obj{
        if( obj == nil){
        [NSException raise:@"null pointer" format:@"Reason"];
    }
    return self;
  }
@end
```

Now you can use this method in any nil object as following.
I used simple NSObject itself. sand used copy method to make it crash.

```
NSObject* valuenil = nil;
NSObject* valuCopy = [[NSObject checkSafe:valuenil] copy];
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but what I want is how to make it crash when I don't change my origin code. so I can find out some potential bug like that we use some pointer we forgetting to assign.

Comment: For example , property tableView in ViewController. But ,in fact , we forget to assign the real value to property. But the program executes fine. So  I want a simple approach to find out bug like this.